# Using GhostDoc to generate Comments for attributes on properties

Tags: attributes, comments, ghostdoc

How can I configure GhostDoc to generate comments for attributes on properties such as this:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required.")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name must be less than 50 characters.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy

move to Tools --> GHostDoc--> Options --> Rules --> Properties --> Double click your required type and set the comments generation rule.

Comment: By no means is it easy to make those adjustments to the standard template. I'm looking at the boilerplate C# template. Yes, it is easy to find where the configuration takes place, though. This thread could do with a nice example of what @SetiSeeker is asking. An example of how it is not easy for everyone: http://bensnose.blogspot.com/2014/07/configuring-ghostdoc-pro-part-1-file.html